# Data encoding error

Tags: encoding, utf-8, psycopg2

My problem is I got following encoding error while copying data from csv files into a database table.

psycopg2.DataError: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xf8
HINT:  This error can also happen if the byte sequence does not match the encoding expected by the server, which is controlled by "client_encoding".

I am not using any encoding and decoding command. And in order to copy data from file to a table I am using following code.

```
cur.copy_from(myFile, myTable)
```

And these files contains lot of special characters and wierd data. But I want to store all these data.

```
EDIT
```

The table is :

create table myTable(id integer, name character varying(10000));

and the sample of csv file is:

```
 "1";"This is  |_|¨^~~ || ¨text wuth special charater like BjÑˆ;; ø"
 "2";"Test data  -._.- (2010/10/11) "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write that you are not specifying any encoding, and it seems like psycopg2 defaults to [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) then. `0xf8` isn't a valid single-byte UTF-8 code point.

Is your source file possibly in [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso-8859-1#Codepage_layout) where `0xf8` corresponds to `ø`?

Edit:

There are several places where this problem could be addressed, and which of them is correct depends on your situation.

- If you repeatedly will have to import ISO-8859-1-files you might want to work with [encoding](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.encoding) to make your script consistent.
- If you only need to do this import once, why not simply convert the files to the expected format outside of Python, with for example [iconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/documentation/libiconv/iconv.1.html) or [recode](http://www.gnu.org/software/recode/)?

Comment: or -15 if you have euro signs

Comment: @Stephan: Yes, ISO-8859-15 is also a possibility, as is more or less any 8-bit encoding. All ISO-8859 variants have a code point at 0xf8.

Answer (score 0):

What is the data type of the column in the database? It should fit whatever you want to put into.

If you want to store byte data, use a binary data type.
If you want to store text data, use a character data type.

You cannot expect that your database can store a `.jpg` file as text, simply because it *isn't* text.

Comment: The datatype of my table contains character varying(10000) and integer. And I am not trying to store any .jpg file as a text. I receive this error as I have lot of special character in text, something like : "|_|" , but I want to store them as it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store it as is, you cannot use a character datatype. Or at least not one where validity to an encoding is checked. It sounds like the input data is not UTF8 encoded.

You can either fix the encoding or switch to another datatype.
If you have multiple input files with different encodings you might run into interesting comparing problems when you try to compare characters that don't exist in all encodings.

Comment: which data type I should use in order to save characters of these types

Comment: Uhm, bytearray? bytes is an alias for str, so that might not work.